# Auto Layout - make a view's dimensions dependent on another view's

Tags: ios, uikit, autolayout

Simple deal: I'd like to make a UIView's width half of its superview's width. Here's my code:

```
//Display a red rectangle:
UIView *redBox = [[UIView alloc] init];
[redBox setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[redBox setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:redBox];

//Make its height equal to its superview's,
//minus standard spacing on top and bottom:
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[redBox]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"redBox": redBox}];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];

//Make its width half of its superviews's width (the problem):
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:redBox
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.view
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  multiplier:0.5
                                  constant:0.0
                                  ];

[self.view addConstraint:constraint];

[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

This is what I get:

[image]

If I set `multiplier` to `1.0`, then the view's width is half of its superview. But why is that?

Comment: It might be useful to put a background color on `self.view`, just to make sure that it is also the size you expect.

Comment: Done, I updated the question and the screenshot. It's a fresh UIViewController, so the `self.view` should have default dimensions.

Comment: Where is this code called? viewDidLoad? a separate method? Try calling [self.view layoutIfNeeded] if this is called after viewDidLoad.

Comment: yep, it's called in `viewDidLoad`. I tried calling `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` but it doesn't help. If you copy and paste it into an empty ViewController's `viewDidLoad` you should get the same results.

Comment: `layoutIfNeeded` shouldn't be necessary, as the view will automatically run layout again whenever a constraint is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that your red box view is under-constrained. You've given it a width, but nothing to tell it where it should position itself horizontally. Since it should be half the width of the superview, it could choose to position itself on the left half of the superview. Or the right half. Or the middle. You didn't specify, so the framework just gets to pick something.

In this case, it looks like it's choosing to align the *center* of the red box with the left edge of the superview. This seems like an odd choice, but again, you didn't specify anything. It can pick whatever it wants.

Add another constraint that will position the view horizontally. That should fix the problem.

Comment: You're right. My code **was** giving the subview the correct size, but a part of it was outside the view's frame.

I had to add this:
     `constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                  constraintWithItem:redBox
                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                  toItem:self.view
                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                  multiplier:1.0
                  constant:0.0
                  ];`